# onClick of javascript not working in Browser like chrome,firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Sir,

I have Javascript calendar(for Picking a date) downloaded from Internet. i am able to pick a appropriate Date when working in IE 6 version.  But it is unable to pick a date(on click not working)  when I am using Modern Browser like Google chrome. here is code Snippet. Advice Kindly!

```
  calendar.js file

        monthMaxDays    = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    monthMaxDaysLeap= [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    hideSelectTags = [];

    function getRealYear(dateObj)
    {
    return (dateObj.getYear() % 100) + 
      (((dateObj.getYear() % 100) < 39) ?                     2000 :        1900);
     }

      function getDaysPerMonth(month, year)
     {
/* 
Check for leap year. These are some conditions to check
      year is leap year or        not...
1.Years evenly divisible by four are normally leap years, except for... 
2.Years also evenly divisible by 100 are not leap years, except for... 
3.Years also evenly divisible by 400 are leap years. 
*/
if ((year % 4) == 0)
{
    if ((year % 100) == 0 && (year % 400) != 0)
        return monthMaxDays[month];

    return monthMaxDaysLeap[month];
}
else
    return monthMaxDays[month];
      }

      function createCalender(year, month, day)
       {
 // current Date
var curDate = new Date();
var curDay = curDate.getDate();
var curMonth = curDate.getMonth();
var curYear = getRealYear(curDate)

 // if a date already exists, we calculate some values here
if (!year)
{
    var year = curYear;
    var month = curMonth;
}

var yearFound = 0;
for (var i=0; i<document.getElementById('selectYear').options.length; i++)
{
    if (document.getElementById('selectYear').options[i].value == year)
    {
        document.getElementById('selectYear').selectedIndex = i;
        yearFound = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!yearFound)
{
    document.getElementById('selectYear').selectedIndex = 0;
    year = document.getElementById('selectYear').options[0].value;      
}
document.getElementById('selectMonth').selectedIndex = month;

 // first day of the month.
var fristDayOfMonthObj = new Date(year, month, 1);
var firstDayOfMonth = fristDayOfMonthObj.getDay();

continu     = true;
firstRow    = true;
var x   = 0;
var d   = 0;
var trs = []
var ti = 0;
while (d <= getDaysPerMonth(month, year))
{
    if (firstRow)
    {
        trs[ti] = document.createElement("TR");
        if (firstDayOfMonth > 0)
        {
            while (x < firstDayOfMonth)
            {
                trs[ti].appendChild 
                     (document.createElement       ("TD"));
                x++;
            }
        }
        firstRow = false;
        var d = 1;
    }
    if (x % 7 == 0)
    {
        ti++;
        trs[ti] = document.createElement("TR");
    }
    if ( day && d == day)
    {
        var setID = 'calenderChoosenDay';
        var styleClass = 'choosenDay';
        var setTitle = 'this day is currently selected';
    }
    else if (d == curDay && month == curMonth && year == curYear)
    {
        var setID = 'calenderToDay';
        var styleClass = 'toDay';
        var setTitle = 'this day today';
    }
    else
    {
        var setID = false;
        var styleClass = 'normalDay';
        var setTitle = false;
    }
    var td = document.createElement("TD");
    td.className = styleClass;
    if (setID)
    {
        td.id = setID;
    }
    if (setTitle)
    {
        td.title = setTitle;
    }
    td.onmouseover = new Function('highLiteDay(this)');
    td.onmouseout = new Function('deHighLiteDay(this)');


    *if (targetEl)
        td.onclick = new Functio*
            ('pickDate  ('+year+', '+month+', '+d+')');
    else
        td.style.cursor = 'default';
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(d));
    trs[ti].appendChild(td);
    x++;
    d++;
 }
return trs;
         } 

        function showCalender(elPos, tgtEl)
       {
targetEl = false;

if (document.getElementById(tgtEl))
{
    targetEl = document.getElementById(tgtEl);
}
else
{
    if (document.forms[0].elements[tgtEl])
    {
        targetEl = document.forms[0].elements[tgtEl];
    }
}
var calTable = document.getElementById('calenderTable');

var positions = [0,0];
var positions = getParentOffset(elPos, positions);  
calTable.style.left = positions[0]+'px';        
calTable.style.top = positions[1]+'px';         

calTable.style.display='block';

var matchDate = new RegExp('^([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})$');
var m = matchDate.exec(targetEl.value);
if (m == null)
{
    trs = createCalender(false, false, false);
    showCalenderBody(trs);
}
else
{
    if (m[1].substr(0, 1) == 0)
        m[1] = m[1].substr(1, 1);
    if (m[2].substr(0, 1) == 0)
        m[2] = m[2].substr(1, 1);
    m[2] = m[2] - 1;
    trs = createCalender(m[3], m[2], m[1]);
    showCalenderBody(trs);
}

hideSelect(document.body, 1);
     }
       function showCalenderBody(trs)
      {
var calTBody = document.getElementById('calender');
while (calTBody.childNodes[0])
{
    calTBody.removeChild(calTBody.childNodes[0]);
}
for (var i in trs)
{
    calTBody.appendChild(trs[i]);
}
      }
      function setYears(sy, ey)
       {
 // current Date
var curDate = new Date();
var curYear = getRealYear(curDate);
if (sy)
    startYear = curYear;
if (ey)
    endYear = curYear;
document.getElementById('selectYear').options.length = 0;
var j = 0;
for (y=ey; y>=sy; y--)
{
    document.getElementById('selectYear')[j++] = new Option(y, y);
}
       }
     function hideSelect(el, superTotal)
       {
if (superTotal >= 100)
{
    return;
}

var totalChilds = el.childNodes.length;
for (var c=0; c<totalChilds; c++)
{
    var thisTag = el.childNodes[c];
    if (thisTag.tagName == 'SELECT')
    {
        if (thisTag.id != 'selectMonth' && thisTag.id != 'selectYear')
        {
            var calenderEl =                  document.getElementById                             ('calenderTable');
            var positions = [0,0];
            var positions = getParentOffset(thisTag, positions);    // nieuw
            var thisLeft    = positions[0];
            var thisRight   = positions[0] + thisTag.offsetWidth;
            var thisTop = positions[1];
            var thisBottom  = positions[1] + thisTag.offsetHeight;
            var calLeft = calenderEl.offsetLeft;
            var calRight    = calenderEl.offsetLeft + calenderEl.offsetWidth;
            var calTop  = calenderEl.offsetTop;
            var calBottom   = calenderEl.offsetTop + calenderEl.offsetHeight;

            if (
                (
                    /* check if it overlaps horizontally */
                    (thisLeft >= calLeft && thisLeft <= calRight)
                        ||
                    (thisRight <= calRight && thisRight >= calLeft)
                        ||
                    (thisLeft <= calLeft && thisRight >= calRight)
                )
                    &&
                (
                    /* check if it overlaps vertically */
                    (thisTop >= calTop && thisTop <= calBottom)
                        ||
                    (thisBottom <= calBottom && thisBottom >= calTop)
                        ||
                    (thisTop <= calTop && thisBottom >= calBottom)
                )
            )
            {
                hideSelectTags[hideSelectTags.length] = thisTag;
                thisTag.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }

    }
    else if(thisTag.childNodes.length > 0)
    {
        hideSelect(thisTag, (superTotal+1));
    }
}
      }
          function closeCalender()
         {
for (var i=0; i<hideSelectTags.length; i++)
 {
    hideSelectTags[i].style.display = 'block';
}
hideSelectTags.length = 0;
document.getElementById('calenderTable').style.display='none';
      } 
       function highLiteDay(el)
    {
el.className = 'hlDay';
     }
       function deHighLiteDay(el)
   { 
if (el.id == 'calenderToDay')
    el.className = 'toDay';
else if (el.id == 'calenderChoosenDay')
    el.className = 'choosenDay';
else
    el.className = 'normalDay';
     }
     function pickDate(year, month, day)
     {
month++;
day = day < 10 ? '0'+day : day;
month   = month < 10 ? '0'+month : month;
if (!targetEl)
{
    alert('target for date is not set yet');
}
else
{
    targetEl.value= year+'-'+month+'-'+day;
    closeCalender();
}
      }
       function getParentOffset(el, positions)
     {
positions[0] += el.offsetLeft;
positions[1] += el.offsetTop;
if (el.offsetParent)
    positions = getParentOffset(el.offsetParent, positions);
return positions;
        }
```

Comment: I would recommend finding code somewhere else; that code is badly written, and as you noted, doesn't work. It would be easier to find a different one than to fix the old one.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, `new Function()`? Really?

```
td.onmouseover = function() {highLiteDay(this);};
td.onmouseout = function() {deHighLiteDay(this);};
// the above two should probably just be `:hover` styles in CSS

(function(year,month,d) {
    td.onclick = function() {pickDate(year, month, d);};
})(year,month,d);
// this creates a closure to "anchor" the values of the variables
// even as the loop iterates
```

Comment: above suggested code change doesnot work here in Google chrome, I mean I am not able to select the Date. Kindly refer Image attached . Thanks If you cannot see the Image, here is message

target for Date is not set yet